# problem with uploading a laravel project on cpanel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with uploading my laravel project on cpanel ,i uploaded all files but in the browser keep showing 
"This site can’t be reached
 server IP address could not be found.

Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.."

Comment: Did you update `APP_URL` to the correct server in `config/app.php`? Is the error from the browser or from Laravel?

Comment: yes ,i did change the APP_URL .the error on the browser @Worthwelle

Comment: I'd be looking at your DNS settings and making sure they're correct. "Server IP address not found" probably isn't a Laravel issue. If you give us the domain perhaps we can help more.

Comment: Dosn't seem like a laravel problem. Does a static page load?